# Genetic algorithm optimize and minimize

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I'm using a Genetic Algorithm to increase a certain value and decrease another.

I'm trying to find the best parameters for a trading strategy. There are 2 values important for me. The netto profit and the maximum drawdown. Maximum drawdown is created by holding a bad trade.

Is there a mathematical formula that I can use to feed these two parameters and create a score for my GA? It would be nice if it was weighted as well, so that I could say that, for instance, I value net profit twice as much as max drawdown

Comment: Managed to get some progress by increasing the distance between the net profit and the max drawdown. I'm still unsure if this is the correct mathematical approach for it though

Comment: Got even more progress by normalizing my profit and drawdown and create a weighted sum of these numbers. The weighted sum allowed me to say that I care about profit twice as much as drawdown, which is nice.